# find total number of days between two dates in iphone

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I would like to find total number of days between two dates.

e.g. today is 01-01-2011(DD-MM-YYYY) and  second date is (25-03-2011), how would I find the total number of days?

```
NSDate *currentdate=[NSDate date];
NSLog(@"curretdate is ==%@",currentdate);
NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
[tempFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-YYYY hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *toDate = [tempFormatter1 dateFromString:@"20-04-2011 09:00:00"];

NSLog(@"toDate ==%@",toDate);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get number of days between two dates objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075183/how-to-get-number-of-days-between-two-dates-objective-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I compare two dates, return a number of days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548008/how-can-i-compare-two-dates-return-a-number-of-days)

Answer (score 10):

In your date Format tor u set wrong it`s be dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss . may be that was the problem.. u get wrong date and not get answer i send litte bit code for get day diffrence.

```
  NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
 [tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
  NSDate *startdate = [tempFormatter dateFromString:@"15-01-2011 09:00:00"];
  NSLog(@"startdate ==%@",startdate);

  NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
  [tempFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
  NSDate *toDate = [tempFormatter1 dateFromString:@"20-01-2011 09:00:00"];
  NSLog(@"toDate ==%@",toDate);

   int i = [startdate timeIntervalSince1970];
   int j = [toDate timeIntervalSince1970];

   double X = j-i;

   int days=(int)((double)X/(3600.0*24.00));
   NSLog(@"Total Days Between::%d",days);
```

---

**Edit 1:**

we can find date difference using following function :

```
-(int)dateDiffrenceFromDate:(NSString *)date1 second:(NSString *)date2 {
    // Manage Date Formation same for both dates
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:date1];
    NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:date2];


    unsigned flags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *difference = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];

    int dayDiff = [difference day];

    return dayDiff;
}
```

from Abizern`s ans. find more infromation for NSDateComponent [**here.**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Be careful, this does not takes hours shift into account. For example if the difference is e.g. 1.6 days, it may return 1 day instead of 2, and this may be worse in the special case there have been a DST switch between the two dates. Prefer using NSDateComponents to retrieve date components like days, month, years and so on.

Comment: ok but u can easily understand this simple logic. and anyone make them code after getting idea

Comment: @AJPatel how can i get records from date.example : 12-09-2016 00:00:00 between 12-09-2016 23:59:59

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Use predicate filter on your collection. Like "@"dateField > %@ AND dateField <= %@",startDate,endDate"

Answer (score 6):

```
NSCalendar *Calander = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd"];
[comps setDay:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM"];
[comps setMonth:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
[comps setYear:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH"];
[comps setHour:05];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm"];
[comps setMinute:30];

NSDate *currentDate=[Calander dateFromComponents:comps];

NSLog(@"Current Date is :- '%@'",currentDate);


[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd"];
[comps setDay:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:yourDate] intValue]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM"];
[comps setMonth:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:yourDate] intValue]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
[comps setYear:[[dateFormat stringFromDate:yourDate] intValue]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH"];
[comps setHour:05];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm"];
[comps setMinute:30];

NSDate *reminderDate=[Calander dateFromComponents:comps];

    //NSLog(@"Current Date is :- '%@'",reminderDate);

    //NSLog(@"Current Date is :- '%@'",currentDate);

    NSTimeInterval ti = [reminderDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];

    //NSLog(@"Time Interval is :- '%f'",ti);
    int days = ti/86400;

[dateFormat release];
[Calander release];
[comps release];
```

Hope It will work for you........

Comment: sorry but i can't understand yourDate  and i tried another date and it will give me -145 days difference that thats not true

Answer (score 5):

A simpler way of doing it is:

```
// This just sets up the two dates you want to compare
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"01-01-2011"];
NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"25-03-2011"];

// This performs the difference calculation
unsigned flags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *difference = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];

// This just logs your output
NSLog(@"Start Date, %@", startDate);
NSLog(@"End Date, %@", endDate);
NSLog(@"%ld", [difference day]);
```

And the results are:

> Start Date, 2011-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
>
> End Date, 2011-03-25 00:00:00 +0000
>
> 83

Trying to use and manipulate seconds for calculating time differences is a bad idea. There are a whole load of classes and methods provided by Cocoa for Calendrical calculations and you should use them as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
- (int) daysToDate:(NSDate*) endDate
{
    //dates needed to be reset to represent only yyyy-mm-dd to get correct number of days between two days.
    NSDateFormatter *temp = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [temp setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *stDt = [temp dateFromString:[temp stringFromDate:self]];
    NSDate *endDt =  [temp dateFromString:[temp stringFromDate:endDate]];
    [temp release]; 
    unsigned int unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:stDt  toDate:endDt  options:0];
    int days = [comps day];
    [gregorian release];
    return days;
}
```

Comment: While using precise timing i was receiving wrong time calendar day difference. This is the correct solution! Great!

Comment: Thanks nfrik. Can you help me for other thing?

Comment: You should probably indicate that this was copied from Joshua Weinberg's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3142380/19679

Answer (score 1):

//try it

```
if((![txtFromDate.text isEqualToString:@""]) && (![txtToDate.text isEqualToString:@""]))
    {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
        NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:txtFromDate.text];
        NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:txtToDate.text];
        unsigned flags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *difference = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];

        int dayDiff = [difference day];

        lblNoOfDays.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dayDiff];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

to find the number of dates between start date to end date.

```
 NSCalendar *cale=[[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    unsigned unitFlags=NSMonthCalendarUnit| NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *comp1=[cale components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];

    NSInteger days=[comp1 day];
    NSLog(@"Days %ld",(long)days);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *dateA;
NSDate *dateB;

NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:dateA
                                             toDate:dateB
                                            options:0];

NSLog(@"Difference in date components: %i/%i/%i", components.day, components.month, components.year);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//write this code in .h file
{
    NSDate *startDate,*EndDate;
    NSDateFormatter *Date_Formatter;
}
//write this code in .h file`enter code here`
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Date_Formatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [Date_Formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    UIToolbar *numbertoolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    numbertoolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    numbertoolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Next"
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],nil];
    [numbertoolbar sizeToFit];

    Txt_Start_Date.inputAccessoryView = numbertoolbar;
    [Txt_Start_Date setInputView:Picker_Date];
    Txt_End_Date.inputAccessoryView = numbertoolbar;
    [Txt_End_Date setInputView:Picker_Date];
    [Picker_Date addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextfield:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)doneWithNumberPad
{

    if ([Txt_Start_Date isFirstResponder])
    {
        [Txt_Start_Date resignFirstResponder];
        [Txt_End_Date becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if([Txt_End_Date isFirstResponder])
    {
        [Txt_End_Date resignFirstResponder];

        startDate =[Date_Formatter dateFromString:Txt_Start_Date.text];
        EndDate =[Date_Formatter dateFromString:Txt_End_Date.text];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate toDate:EndDate options:0];
        Lab_Total_Days.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",components.day];
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this. Hope it helps you...

```
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// Set the date format according to your needs
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm a"]; //for 12 hour format
//[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm "]  // for 24 hour format
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:firstDateString];
NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:secondDatestring];
NSLog(@"%@f is the time difference",[date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]);
[df release];
```