# How to get number of days between two dates objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I'm trying to make a label that says how many days left till event. I want to calculate the difference between todays date and the events date. I'm using this code and its giving me -4600. It works fine till I use todays date.

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                        fromDate:startDate
                                                          toDate:endDate
                                                         options:0];
    return components.day;
return components.day;
```

Comment: The one question where you say is a duplicate I've used that answer and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you verify that `NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end]` returns the expected date? - What does the string `end` contain?

Comment: @user1898829 Then you should have mentioned that in your question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default `[NSDate date]` return date in like `2013-08-06 08:50:25 +0000`
and you have set your formatter to `yyyy-MM-dd` this, so you have to convert your startDate to `yyyy-MM-dd` this form..

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"%@",startDate);
    NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];
    NSLog(@"%@",endDate);


    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                        fromDate:startDate
                                                          toDate:endDate
                                                         options:0];
    return components.day;
```