# Print dates between 2 given dates

Tags: ios, nsdate

I want to print the inbetween dates between 2 given dates .

e.g if `fromDate=12/10/2014` and `toDate=15/10/2014` then I want this,

```
12/10/2014

13/10/2014

14/10/2014

15/10/2014.
```

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: unable to understand you

Comment: i want to get dates between 2 given dates like the example given above

Comment: get date difference between 2 dates (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075183/how-to-get-number-of-days-between-two-dates-objective-c) and then using for loop add day+1 using date components.

Comment: can you show me how as i am not getting it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
//datemin= fromdate , datemax=todate
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *days = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSInteger dayCount = 0;
    while ( TRUE ) {
        [days setDay: ++dayCount];
        NSDate *date = [gregorianCalendar dateByAddingComponents: days toDate: datemin options: 0];
        if ( [date compare: dateMax] == NSOrderedDescending )
            break;
        NSLog(@"%@",date);
        // Do something with date like add it to an array, etc.
    }
```