# how to find number of days

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone - get number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075356/iphone-get-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

I am trying to compare 2 dates and find out the number of day in between them.

something like below:

```
now = [NSDate date];

// This is i am saving in NSUSerdefault on some condition,like 

if (a == 1) {

    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS";
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSLog(@"The Current Time is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);
    datesaved = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]];
    NSLog(@"old date saved : %@",datesaved);

    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

and 
find current date .

Now i want to compare current date with the date saved in `NSUserDefaults` to find number of day in between them.

ex:

> The Current Time is 2012-12-16 19:12:74 
>   old date saved :    2012-12-12
>   19:12:74

Number of days : 4

Thanks

Comment: By the way, the HH:MM:SS should probably be HH:mm:ss. MM is grabbing the month! And, looking at your example, SS gives the fractional second (74 in your example!), not the number of seconds. See [date format patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: pow(duplicate,09823984712947) times these NSdate questions are there. I would suggest to make NSDateOverflow... :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-02-03 00:00:00 +0000"];

NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

int numberOfDays = secondsBetween / 86400;

NSLog(@"There are %d days in between the two dates.", numberOfDays);
```

Comment: This tells you the number of 24 hour periods and not days. What if it is from 10pm to 2am?  One day has passed, but only 4 hours.

Comment: note, that due to daylight saving times and leap seconds a day's length can vary between 82440 and 90001 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the day component of a date this way:

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date]; // Or date from format
NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [cal components: NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate: now];
NSInteger day = [components day];
```

Do the same for the other date and compare them.

Comment: not getting this one....how should i do that for old date?

Comment: Well if they're in the same month, you can take also the days of the older date (same procedure), and then compute the difference.